# Copying (assembling) the column from smaller data frames into the bigger data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, indexing

I have a data frame with measurements for several groups of participants,  and I am doing some calculations for each group.  I want to add a column in a big data frame (all participants), from secondary data frames (partial list of participants).

When I do merge a couple of times (merging a new data frame to the existing one), it creates a duplicate of the column instead of one column.

As the size of the dataframes is different I can not compare them directly.

I tried

```
    #df1 - main bigger dataframe,  df2 - smaller dataset contains group of df1
    
    
    for i in range(len(df1)):
    # checking indeces to place the data to correct participant:
        if df1.index[i] not in df2['index']: 
            pass
        else :
            df1['rate'][i] = list(df2[rate][df2['index']==i])
```

It does not work properly though. Can you please help with the correct way of assembling the column?
update: where the index of the initial dataframe and the "index" column of the calculation is the same, copy the rate value from the calculation into main df

main dataframe 1df

| index | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |

dataframe with calculated values

| index | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value |
| 4 | value |
| 6 | value |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |

output df

| index | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | value |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | value |

Comment: Could you provide example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @ozacha Thank you, I've updated it, basically  where the index of the initial data frame and the "index" column of the calculation is the same, copy the rate value from the calculation into main df  1df

Answer (score 1):

Try this – using `.join()` to merge dataframes on their indices and combining two columns using `.combine_first()`:

```
df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix="_df1", rsuffix="_df2")
df["rate"] = df["rate_df2"].combine_first(df["rate_df1"])
```

**EDIT:**

This assumes both dataframes use a matching index. If that is not the case for `df2`, run this first:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('index')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does not put the values into the correct places. the second dataframe "index" column is a copy of the main df index to preserve the correct order of entries. So  I need them to match to place the value into the correct corresponding space, join does not preserve the order

Comment: @VittoTitto If `df2` uses a different index, you can align them with `df2 = df2.set_index('index')`